# Hardware requirements for VLC based transcoding

Tags: vlc-media-player

I have a device which give me raw mpeg2 multicast udp video streams. And I'm going to build a server which will transcode (based on VLC) these streams into h264, I have 20 of such streams. My question is : What are the approximate hardware requirements for such a server ?

Comment: Why don't you actually try encoding a few of these streams on a machine you do have and extrapolate hardware requirements from that?

Answer (score 2):

**The short answer** (totally guessing at all your requirements): ridiculous. You'd need stream processing cards (like nVidia's Tesla cards) or monster processing ability.

**The long answer**: It's impossible to say. If you crank the quality way down, to unacceptable levels for almost all applications, then a modern multi-core server could handle twenty streams. You didn't mention the input bit rate, resolution, or audio requirements.

Venturing a guess, you've got an [HD HomeRun](http://silicondust.com) or similar product, sourcing ~5Mb HD Video streams from a cable provider or broadcast. If you simply wanted to transcode 20 such streams to "normal" [x264](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X264) and MP3 or AAC audio, it would without a doubt require processing add-on cards.

I have a HD HomeRum, my 3 year old quad-core home server can transcode to x264/QP=25 and MP3/Med (with a good number of quality & speed optimizations, available upon request) using [mencoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu) at roughly 1.5x realtime (meaning it can't even do two video steams at a time, if I'm recording multiple shows they have to be queued and processed later).

Answer (score 1):

Two Core i7 950 (10-14 channels per server depending on transcoding parameters) will be sufficient for your requirements. You will have 50%-70% load on the CPU for each server. Also you don't need very much ram, and 8G will be good enough.